# Is there any way in C++ to move item from one std::map to another with preserving the iterators?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, extract, move

here is I want to achieve:

Lets say I have 2 `std::map<int,int>` containers with items

- `m1 = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}};`
- `m2 = {{4,4}, {5,5}};`

And I have an iterator referencing to the second item from `m1` (`{2,2}`)

```
auto it = m1.find(2);
```

Now I want to move the item with key 2 from `m1` to `m2` and so the iterator `it` should refer to the right element inside the `m2` without reassigning.

Before moving:

```
m1 = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}}
               ^
              it

m2 = {{4,4}, {5,5}}
```

After moving:

```
m1 = {{1,1}, {3,3}}

m2 = {{2,2}, {4,4}, {5,5}}
        ^
        it
```

So far I have wrote the code that do what I want:

```
std::map<int,int> m1 {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}};
std::map<int,int> m2 {{4,4}, {5,5}};

auto it = m1.find(2);

m2.insert(std::move(m1.extract(m1.find(2))));
```

But the specification says that iterators referencing to the extracted items are invalidated.
So is it safe to use the iterator to the element after it was moved with `extract` method? Or is there any other way to achieve what I want?

I would appreciate any thoughts, thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Why not to use the iterator returned by `m2.insert(...);`?

Comment: @Evg, not an option for my case.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the answer, but I really don't understand why it is ok to reuse iterators of merged map after performing `map::merge` and not ok to reuse iterator after extract and move?
It works exactly as I need, and while testing so far I didn't find any issues with this approach. Is it really unsafe? 
I'm asking just because it will save me significant amount of time if there is any change to safely reuse iterators in such way I explained...

Comment: @IlliaMoroz why is using the `iterator` returned by `m2.insert()` not an option? Once `extract()` is called, `it` is invalidated, so it must be reassigned.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the code above is just an example. In my real project I have a structure that stores iterators of `map` containers to be able to quickly travel through that containers. I don't have access to the instances of such structures, so reassigning is not an option for me.

Comment: @IlliaMoroz What you are asking for is essentially: `iterator it1 = ...; auto it2 = m1.find(2); m2.insert(m1.extract(it2));` and have `it1` updated automatically. There is no way to do that. `extract()` invalidates all iterators to the extracted element, so those iterators MUST be reassigned to the iterator returned by `insert()`. If you don't have access to the effected iterators, then you have a broken design, and can't use `extract()` at all. Maybe you should use pointers to elements rather than iterators to elements? `extract()` does not invalidate pointers to elements that are re-inserted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you actually fill these maps, but rather naive solution which comes to my mind without any bigger context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using MyCustomMap = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>*>;

std::pair<int, int>* findInMyCustomMap(const MyCustomMap& my_map, int key) {
    for(const auto& i : my_map) {
        if(i->first == key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
std::pair<int, int> el1{1,1};
std::pair<int, int> el2{2,2};
std::pair<int, int> el3{3,3};
std::pair<int, int> el4{4,4};
std::pair<int, int> el5{5,5};

MyCustomMap m1{{&el1, &el2, &el3}};
MyCustomMap m2{{&el4, &el5}};

const auto it = findInMyCustomMap(m1, 2);

m2.insert(m2.begin(), it);

std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SJL1ma_xP

Please keep in mind the scope/life of the objects referenced, though.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns an `iterator` to the inserted element.  There is no way to make your `it` variable magically start pointing from `m1` to `m2`, especially since [`std::map::extract()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) "**invalidates the iterators to the extracted element**", so you MUST reassign `it` after the extraction, eg:

```cpp
auto it = m1.find(2);
if (it != m1.end())
    it = m2.insert(m1.extract(it)).position;
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
auto it = m2.insert(m1.extract(2)).position;
```

Since you want `it` to point at the element moved into `m2`, you must use the new `iterator` that `insert()` returns to you.  The old iterator has been invalidated and can no longer be used.